# Finding duplicates from MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say I have a validations table like below.

```
     validation_id    scenario_id
     100              1
     101              1
     102              1
     103              2
     104              2
     100              3
     101              3
     102              3
```

In the above table if we observe the scenario id's 1 and 3 have the same validation Id's 100, 101 and 102.

In this scenario I can say scenario_id=1 is a duplicate of scenario_id=3.

can I get a MySql query to find such duplicates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way of thinking about it is to find all instances where there are null differences between datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select validation_ids, group_concat(scenario_id)
from (select scenario_id,
             group_concat(validation_id order by validation_id) as validation_ids
      from validations v
      group by scenario_id
     ) v
group by validation_ids
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: what is 't' in the above sub query?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . .Why?  The OP wants different ids that have the same validations and specifically does not want `scenario_id = 2`, because it has no duplicates.

Comment: Is there any other solution, if there is a column of type varchar(1000) in place of scenario_id and need to find the duplicates with same logic..

Comment: @sandkar. . . (1) You can use `group_concat()` but you need to increase the `group_concat_max_len` environment parameter.  (2) That would be a different question, which you can ask as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT validation_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(scenario_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS scenario_ids
FROM (

    SELECT scenario_id, GROUP_CONCAT(validation_id ORDER BY validation_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS validation_ids
    FROM (

        SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT      100 validation_id, 1 scenario_id
        UNION SELECT     101 validation_id, 1 scenario_id
        UNION SELECT     102 validation_id, 1 scenario_id
        UNION SELECT     103 validation_id, 2 scenario_id
        UNION SELECT     104 validation_id, 2 scenario_id
        UNION SELECT     100 validation_id, 3 scenario_id
        UNION SELECT     101 validation_id, 3 scenario_id
        UNION SELECT     102 validation_id, 3 scenario_id) A

        ) B

    GROUP BY scenario_id
) C

GROUP BY validation_ids
```